# How to check if python function return true or false

Tags: python, return, boolean

**I am trying to run this code but getting an error:**
[image: Error I am facing]

My code:

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, marks,age):
       self.student_id=student_id
       self.marks=marks
       self.age=age

    def validate_age(self):
        if self.age >20:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def validate_marks(self):
        if self.marks>0 and self.marks<100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def check_qualification(self):
        if (validate_age)==True and if(validate_marks)==True:
            if self.marks>65:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    def set(self,x):
        self.__student_id=x

    def get(self):
        if (check_qualification==True):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Please include your complete error traceback as **text** in the question itself and edit the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you could just change the line

```
if (validate_age)==True and if(validate_marks)==True:
```

to

```
if self.validate_age() and self.validate_marks():
```

Note that, since those functions already return booleans, it's redundant to add `== True`. It's enough to simply call the functions.

You'll probably also have to change the line in get()

```
if (check_qualification==True):
```

to

```
if self.check_qualification():
```

The compiler is getting confused because you're not actually calling the functions in your code.